# What is suitable version(s) for Dymamic web module with JavaSE 1.6 SDK, Tomcat 6 x64?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

We need maintain old system and research arround. I am using Windows 10 x64, Eclipse IDE 2022-12, JDK 1.6, Tomcat 6 and Spring 2.5.6 (include `spring-jms-2.5.6.jar` , `spring-orm-2.5.6.java` , `spring-context-support-2.5.6.jar` , `spring-tx-2.5.6.jar` , `spring-aop-2.5.6.jar` , `spring-web-2.5.6.jar` , `spring-jdbc-2.5.6.jar` , `spring-beans-2.5.6.jar` , `spring-core-2.5.6.jar` , `spring-context-2.5.6.jar` ), Ant build inside Eclipse IDE 2022-12.

. **What is suitable version(s) for Dymamic web module with JavaSE 1.6 SDK, Tomcat 6 x64?** Please give me official/reference links about these if you know.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Given the fact that tomcat 7 was released back in 2010, I would say none of them. Given the fact that it is a legacy system, and that you have to maintain it, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985916/dynamic-web-module-option-in-eclipse) says 2.5.

Comment: "*Please give me official/reference links about these if you know.*" - [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other **off-site resource** are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I already read it before you given me. My question is very specific, no vauge. As you know, you given link with answer what not include reference document link(s).

Answer (score 0):

Dyamic web version = Servlet specification version.

> Full Java 6 and Java EE 5 support (JDBC 4.0, JTA 1.1, JavaMail 1.4,
> JAX-WS 2.0)

and

> Spring 2.5 is still compatible with JDK 1.4.2+ and J2EE 1.3+. Java 1.4
> users

https://spring.io/blog/2007/11/19/spring-framework-2-5-released
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/radfws/9.6.1?topic=project-dynamic-web-projects-applications
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javaee/javaeetechnologies.html#javaee5

[image]

==> Choose 2.5